# Error when running a container using --name flag

Tags: docker

when trying to run docker with a container name, I get the following error  (on macOS)

```
~$ docker run -it myifort --name cont 
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "--name": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Without the --name flag everything works as expected.

Comment: Anything you pass after the image name `myifort` is interpreted as the command to run, and overrides the Dockerfile `CMD`.  Docker options like `--name` need to be before the image name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `docker run -it --name cont myifort`

Comment: no it gives me the same error. I need -it because I need to run a shell interactively. my image name is myifort. A container is created, but not with the name I want

Comment: try `docker run -it --name cont myifort`

Comment: that works thanks